# How to save the MapReduce result in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I have two collections: PriceShop(ShopId, Price, DrugId), Drug(DrugId, MaxPrice, MinPrice).

I use map/reduce to find the maxPrice, minPrice of the same drug in the PriceShop Collection, and then use the map/reduce result to update the Drug collection.

But in MongoDb 2.4, i can no longer use "db.Drug.Update" in map or reduce function, then is there any other solution to do this. Here is my map/reduce code:
 db.PriceShop.MapReduce(map, reduce);

```
function Map() {
emit(this.Drugid, {
    "count" : 0.5,
    "maxprice" : this.Price,
    "minprice" : this.Price,
    "stateid" : this.State
});
emit(this.Drugid, {
    "count" : 0.5,
    "maxprice" : this.Price,
    "minprice" : this.Price,
    "stateid" : this.State
});
}

function Reduce(key, arr_values) {
var count = 0;
var maxprice = 0;
var minprice = 0;
var drugItem = db.drug.findOne({
        "_id" : key
    });
arr_values.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item["stateid"] == 0) {
        count += item["count"];
        if (item["maxprice"] > maxprice && item["maxprice"] > 0) {
            maxprice = item["maxprice"];
        }
        if (minprice == 0) {
            minprice = item["minprice"];
        } else if (item["minprice"] > 0 && item["minprice"] < minprice) {
            minprice = item["minprice"];
        }
    }

});
var MaxStorePrice = 0;
var MinStorePrice = 0;
var PriceShopCount = 0;
if (drugItem != null && drugItem["MaxStorePrice"] != null) {
    MaxStorePrice = drugItem["MaxStorePrice"];
}
if (drugItem != null && drugItem["MinStorePrice"] != null) {
    MinStorePrice = drugItem["MinStorePrice"];
}
if (drugItem != null && drugItem["PriceShopCount"] != null) {
    PriceShopCount = drugItem["PriceShopCount"];
}
if (MaxStorePrice != maxprice || MinStorePrice != minprice || PriceShopCount != count) {
    db.drug.update({
        "_id" : key
    }, {
        "$set" : {
            "MaxStorePrice" : maxprice,
            "MinStorePrice" : minprice,
            "PriceShopCount" : NumberInt(count)
        }
    });
}
return {
    "count" : count,
    "maxprice" : maxprice,
    "minprice" : minprice,
    "MaxStorePrice" : MaxStorePrice,
    "MinStorePrice" : MinStorePrice,
    "PriceShopCount" : PriceShopCount
};
```

}

Comment: Is there anyway to refactor your code so that the output of the Reduce is what you were setting into a collection? (I'm surprised it took 10gen as long as it did to remove the ability to write to collections during a MapReduce).

Comment: @WiredPrairie May be i can just"renturn {"MaxStorePrice" : MaxStorePrice,"MinStorePrice" : MinStorePrice,"PriceShopCount" : PriceShopCount}", and then how can i update it, do i need to use "foreach" to enumerate each item in the output and update? Or just update with the output?

Comment: Can you just set the `out` of the MapReduce call to a new collection and gather the results there?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Hmm, Maybe not, actually now i've set the **out** to a collection "keeptempPriceShop", but it score the document like this:{_id:1,value:{"MaxStorePrice" : MaxStorePrice,"MinStorePrice" : MinStorePrice,"PriceShopCount" : PriceShopCount}}, but my final purpose is to update the Drug collection. Maybe this is a bad design and i go a wrong way, then tell me, thank you.